# Specific Subgroups of an Abelian Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I am looking for an elementary proof of the following result:

If G is a finite abelian group and H is a subgroup of G, then G contains a subgroup isomorphic to G/H.

This can be proved rather easily by using the classification theorem for finite abelian groups, however I am looking for a more elementary proof that doesn't use such a big hammer.

Comment: You can prove this nicely using characters of abelian groups. Don't know if you classify this es elementary.

Comment: More explicitly, a finite abelian group is isomorphic to its dual group ${\rm Hom}(G,{\mathbb C}^*)$, and quotients of a group correspond to subgroups of the dual group.

Comment: @DerekHolt What is a nice proof of that which does not use the classification? I remember trying to do this a long time ago and failing.

Comment: I like the dual group proof because of its elegance, but I certainly wouldn't call that elementary.